# Automatic calendar from dates of events

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, calendar

I have a site WordPress, my client want add, in home, a calendar that contains days and months selected for a multiple events.

for example:

I want add, as a article, an event that contain: " date: 05/05/2013 with title: Marathon to Milan"
so, I want create a calendar that select automatically number and doing a color at 05/05/2013, thanks at event that I created.

This is my website http://www.dencity.info/ and you can see the famous simple calendar and, under slideshow, I've 3 categories (red, green and cyan) with events per category.

At the creation of event (article), I have a field for calendar (generated in WordPress) with datepicker.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the event Calendar Plug-in. 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/cp-multi-view-calendar/ “> cp-multi-view-event-calendar